# PDO prepare statement search error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi can anyone please explain why this query does not work?

It's probably something stupid, but I can't work it out for the life of me!
I want it so all the searches are lowercase

```
// $_UID would be 1

// $_GET['term'] would be 'title'

$_UID = $USER->getCID ();

$sql = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE CID = :cid AND Status='1' AND LOWER(`SiteName`) LIKE LOWER(:term) ORDER BY ID DESC"); 
$sql->bindParam(':cid', $_UID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->bindParam(':term', '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);    //--line27
$sql->execute();
```

> Error:
>   Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\eBusiness\V3\Ajax\job_search.php on line 27

Comment: Does it return error if you remove the concatenation of % from your $_GET['term'] variable?

Comment: $sql->bindParam(':term', 'Title', PDO::PARAM_STR);
when i enter 'Title' direct it works fine

Comment: Does:
$sql->bindParam(':term', '%Title%', PDO::PARAM_STR);  or  
$sql->bindParam(':term', $_GET['term'] , PDO::PARAM_STR);

both work as well?  What is the value of $_GET['term'] when you echo if out before preparing your statement?

Comment: @user3388630 have you tried my answer ? just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bindParam` wants the 2nd parameter to be a reference.  Meaning it need to be a variable passed, not an expression.

```
$_UID = $USER->getCID();
$term = '%'.$_GET['term'].'%';

$sql = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE CID = :cid AND Status='1' AND LOWER(`SiteName`) LIKE LOWER(:term) ORDER BY ID DESC"); 
$sql->bindParam(':cid', $_UID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->bindParam(':term', $term, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

Comment: This worked a treat, sorry for the late reply I got called out! cheers again